# Get Value of TinyMCE listbox and replase selection with it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to add a custom drop-down list on tinymce's  toolbar. The desired functionality is to select the text in the editor. Click on the drop-down list, select the preferred color and transfer the selection to the span tag with this color as the style. I have a problem with extracting the selected element. Here is the code.

```
// theme colors
var posttileBox = null;

ed.addButton( 'theme_colors', {
    text: 'Theme colors',
    type   : 'listbox',
    name   : 't_color',
    label  : 'Theme colors',
    fixedWidth:!0,
    icon: false,
    values : [
        { text: 'transparent', value: 'transparent' },
        { value: '#fff', text: 'white' },
        { value: '#000', text: 'black' },
        { value: '#D1D2D4', text: 'grey' },
        { value: '#F0F2F1', text: 'lightgrey' },
        { value: '#D21F34', text: 'red' }, 
        { value: '#24376F', text: 'blue' },
        { value: '#DEE1E9', text: 'lightblue' },      
    ],
    value : "",
    onPostRender: function() {
        posttileBox = this;
    },
    onclick: function(e) {
        var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
        var return_text = '';
        return_text = '<span style="color:'+posttileBox.value()+';">' + selected_text + '</span>';                    
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
    }
});
```

i already have tried this. But it's not working.

```
e.data.t_color
```

Please give me a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an example of using the listbox in [Tiny MCE API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/demo/custom-toolbar-listbox/) ( often all that is needed somewhere in API ), and in combination with my code I get this

```
ed.addButton( 'theme_colors', {
    text: 'Theme colors',
    type   : 'listbox',
    name   : 't_color',
    label  : 'Theme colors',
    fixedWidth: !0,
    icon: false,
    onselect: function (e) {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setStyle(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), 'color', this.value() );
},
values : [
    { text: 'transparent', value: 'transparent' },
    { value: '#fff', text: 'white' },
    { value: '#000', text: 'black' },
    { value: '#D1D2D4', text: 'grey' },
    { value: '#F0F2F1', text: 'lightgrey' },
    { value: '#D21F34', text: 'red' }, 
    { value: '#24376F', text: 'blue' },
    { value: '#DEE1E9', text: 'lightblue' },      
],
value : "",
onPostRender: function () {
    this.value();
}
```

} );

If someone does not know where to place this code or how to make custom buttons, here’s a good article on [tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182)